# Why does LIKE '%%' depend on irrelative joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge query which runs quite well by itself. It has a lot of `join` statements. So, its structure looks like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable2 t2 ON t2.attr = t.attr1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable3 t3 ON t3.attr = t.attr3
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytableN tN ON tN.attr = t.attrN
```

It runs just for a millisecond. But if I add LIKE statement:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable2 t2 ON t2.attr = t.attr1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable3 t3 ON t3.attr = t.attr3
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytableN tN ON tN.attr = t.attrN
WHERE tK.attrP LIKE '%Something%'
```

then it almost never ends. I could not wait till the end and had to stop it manually. But at the same time, if I rewrite the query just like this

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytablek tK ON tK.attr = t.attr1
WHERE tK.attrP LIKE '%Something%'
```

then it again starts to run like a flash. Why is that? I think, that there is no logic, that all those extra joins which have nothing to do with this field `attrP` have some effect on the speed of the query. I guess, I know how to optimize this query, but still I think that, the more I work with `MySQL`, the less I like it. Hundreds of times I struggled with something which had no reasonable explanation.

**EDIT**

Well, I thought that I knew how to optimize it - to use inner join in this way:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable t
... bunch of joins
INNER JOIN mytablek tK ON tK.attr = t.attr1 AND tK.attrP LIKE '%Something%'
... bunch of joins
```

But this has no effect.

**EDIT**

Well, I found a solution - to use `match against`. But unfortunatelly this solution is not universal. In fact, match against throws an error when you try to search in a field returned by a subquery. Poor mysql

Comment: Most likely, the version with the many joins creates a bigger result set

Comment: You can verify that by doing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select with all joins and without LIKE)` and compare it to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select with one join and without LIKE)`

Comment: @ Daniel Hilgarth . Well, it creates the same result set without this LIKE, even bigger

Comment: It's not about the LIKE, it's about the JOINs! Please check my second comment again

Comment: I think, the result set shouldn't be to large for MySQL - the query with all joins returns just 2.5K rows for milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `WHERE tK.attrP LIKE '%Something%'` probably removes records from the result set. We don't know how many, though. Maybe 1%, maybe 99%.

We don't even know if we only joined mytable with mytableK and used that clause, what percentage of the records would be affected. Would it be worth joining these tables first and with the supposedly few records left, do the other joins using just loops to get those other tables' records? Or should we better join everything first using great join algorithms on the tables and only at last filter with LIKE?

We don't know and the dbms doesn't know either.

But you notice that the dbms is fast on the pure joins, but slow when it applies the LIKE clause. So hint the dbms to do one thing first and the other later:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ... FROM mytable t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable2 t2 ON t2.attr = t.attr1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable3 t3 ON t3.attr = t.attr3
  ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mytableN tN ON tN.attr = t.attrN
)
WHERE tK_attrP LIKE '%Something%';
```

Comment: That is a great idea! I will check it now

Answer (score 1):

The SQL engine has many options when running the query.  One of the strengths of the language is the optimizer which chooses the "best" way to run a given query.  Of course, when the engine things is best is not necessarily the best.

The second point is that your condition is turning the `left join`s to `inner join`s.  So, you might as well write the query that way (for clarity).

With that background, there are two possible answers to your question.  The first is that when you run the other queries, you are noting when results first appear.  This is the "time-to-first-row" measurement.  However, the rows that match your more complicated query are at the end of the input.  And MySQL needs to process all the non-matching rows to find the matching ones.  This would be particularly true if some of the intermediate results create a cartesian product for a given row in the first table.

Another possibility is that the execution plan changes.  Because the `left join`s are really inner joins, MySQL has a lot of flexibility in rewriting them.

My next recommendation is to put the join to table `mytablek` as the first table, rather than the last.  Perhaps that will help MySQL find the best optimization.

The second would be to use a subquery:

```
(select t.*
 from mytablek tk
 where tK.attrP LIKE '%Something%'
) tk
```

This may force the engine to whittle down the rows quickly and point the optimizer in a better direction.

from

Comment: "The second point is that your condition is turning the left joins to inner joins" - as I said this has absolutely no effect. "My next recommendation is to put the join to table mytablek as the first table" - that is also impossible, not in theory, but in practice, of course, because this query is built by a query builder. I can tune the builder itself, but in this case there is no logic that should force me to put this very join first, because the other time the user would like to search by another field